# Not able to retrieve data from the sqlite Database in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am not able to retrieve data from my `sqlite` database. Data is present in it (i checked it by opening my database file manually). The connection to database is being established successfully. my sqlite3_step statement also returns SQLITE_OK. But resultset does not contain anything.!
here's the code snippet:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        databaseReferences = [[DatabaseReferences alloc]init];

        const char *newPath = [databasepath UTF8String];
        int opened = sqlite3_open(newPath, &db);

        if(opened == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Database for processing login query opened successfully...");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Database for processing login query NOT OPENED...");
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Here databaseReferences is an object of a class that contains the `sqlite3` type variable

Actually, in UI side, the user enters username and pwd, and i am matching the fields that user entered with the data already present in my sqlite database. When the user presses LOGIN button. the following happens:

```
-(BOOL)processLoginQueryusername:(NSString *)uname password:(NSString *)pwd
{
    const char *getUsernames = "select Username from LoginTable";
    int outcome = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, getUsernames, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if(outcome != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not find the usernames");
        NSLog(@"the error is %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"got the usernames.. Now checking for valid username and password entry..");

        NSLog(@"the number of columns returned is %d", sqlite3_column_count(statement));

        int i = 0;
        while( sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            [usernameList addObject:name];
            NSLog(@"the Username list array contains %d names", usernameList.count);
            NSLog(@"the name is %@", [usernameList objectAtIndex:i]);
            i++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<usernameList.count; i++)
        {   
            if([uname isEqualToString:[usernameList objectAtIndex:i]])
            {
                NSLog(@"You are an authenticated user..");
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

This is my code of AppDelegate's method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    referenceToDatabase = [[DatabaseReferences alloc]init];
    [referenceToDatabase establishDatabaseConnection];
    [referenceToDatabase release];
    //code for initializing window.. so not including that code
}
```

`referenceToDatabase` is an object of a class that contains sqlite3 variable. Here is my called method:

```
-(BOOL)establishDatabaseConnection
{
    usernameList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dbPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    databaseName = @"TaskManagementDatabase.sql";

    databasepath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"%@",databasepath);

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasepath])
    {
        NSLog(@"the database already exists");
        return YES;
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"database does not exist.. creating the database");
        const char *newPath = [databasepath UTF8String];
        int opened = sqlite3_open(newPath, &db);

        if(opened == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"newly created database opened successfully...");
            [self createBothTables];
            [self insertInitialDataIntoBothTables];
            sqlite3_close(db);
            return YES;
        }
```

This is what I am getting on console:

TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] got the usernames.. Now checking for valid username and password entry..
2013-09-02 11:33:55.134 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the number of columns returned is 1
2013-09-02 11:33:55.135 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the Username list array contains 0 names
2013-09-02 11:33:55.136 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the name is (null)
2013-09-02 11:33:55.136 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the Username list array contains 0 names
2013-09-02 11:33:55.136 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the name is (null)
2013-09-02 11:33:55.137 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the Username list array contains 0 names
2013-09-02 11:33:55.137 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the name is (null)
2013-09-02 11:33:55.137 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the Username list array contains 0 names
2013-09-02 11:33:55.138 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the name is (null)
2013-09-02 11:33:55.138 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the Username list array contains 0 names
2013-09-02 11:33:55.138 TaskListManagementApplication[9838:c07] the name is (null)

Comment: You probably didn't initialize your `usernameList` array.

Comment: yes.. I have initialized the array

Comment: Show the code where you initialize the array. And make sure you initialize the array before calling `processLoginQueryusername`.

Comment: Please check "usernameList" is allocated or not?

Comment: I have initialized it by calling a method in my AppDelegate.. So, as soon as my app launches, it gets initialized..

Comment: I have done it by calling a method in- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: Is this `processLoginQueryusername` method in your `DatabaseReferences` class or some other class?

Comment: Yes.. It is in DatabaseReferences class

Comment: Tell me one thing @rmaddy .. because my while loop in processLoginQueryusername:password: is running 5 times, this means that i have retreived the data from my sqlite database.. i am just not able to out it in my array.. right???

Comment: heyyy.. i tried something and it worked.. I initialized my array just before my while loop in processLoginQueryusername:password:.... and it worked..!!! guess something was wrong with my initialization earlier..

Comment: BTW, don't forget to call `sqlite3_finalize` before you return from `processLoginQueryusername`.